# what is the ajax response limit of json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get a `JSON` as a `AJAX` response when entering to the site .But i want to know is there any length of object that i can get ? `GET` or `POST` ?

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'php'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

Does browser limiting it ? or any restriction from server side ?

Does it depend on browsers ?

1. Firefox
2. Chrome
3. IE
4. Opera

Comment: Is this a general question or are you struggling with something? If it's the latter, by explaining the problem you might find someone has a solution.

Comment: @Popnoodles My browser getting struck  always when i getting large data via angualr.That's why i asked this question

Comment: Ok, if you describe what the program is doing and what data is being returned you might find someone has a better method, for example to return enough data so the user can continue, and pull more data only when required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit to the size of data which can be transferred via JSON. However, a large request, for example anything over 1Mb, will take a long time to receive and even longer for the browser to deserialise.

Comment: You mean doesn't it depend of any case ? any Framework we use ? Jquery,Angular etc

Comment: No, the size of data is unlimited - the same as any HTTP request. The speed is mostly determined by the size of the response.

Comment: Yep, return less data ;)